# HTML Agility Parsing

Tags: c#, xml, linq, html-agility-pack

I would like to parse an HTML table and disaply contents using XML to LINQ in an bound listbox.

I am using HTML Agility pack and using this code.

```
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.SourceURL");
    HtmlNode rateNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel']");
    string rate = rateNode.InnerText;
    this.richTextBox1.Text = rate;
```

The HTML looks like this..

```
<div id="FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel">

   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody>
     <tr class="">
     <td class="airline"><img src="/images/airline logos/NZ.gif" title="AIR NEW ZEALAND LIMITED. " alt="AIR NEW ZEALAND LIMITED. " /></td>
     <td class="flight">NZ8</td>
     <td class="codeshare">&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="origin">San Francisco</td>
     <td class="date">01 Sep</td>
     <td class="time">17:15</td>
     <td class="est">18:00</td>
     <td class="status">DEPARTED</td>
     </tr>
```

But it is returning this

```
NZ8&nbsp;San Francisco01 Sep17:1518:00DEPARTEDAC6103NZ8San Francisco01 Sep17:1518:00DEPARTEDCO6754NZ8San Francisco01 Sep17:1518:00DEPARTEDLH7157NZ8San Francisco01 Sep17:1518:00DEPARTEDUA6754NZ8San Francisco01 Sep17:1518:00DEPARTEDUS5308NZ8San Francisco01 Sep17:1518:00DEPARTEDVS7408NZ8San Francisco01 Sep17:1518:00DEPARTEDEK407&nbsp;Melbourne/Dubai01 Sep17:5017:50DEPARTEDEK413&nbsp;Sydney/Dubai01 Sep18:0018:00DEPARTEDQF44&nbsp;Sydney01
```

What I would like is pasrse this to XML format and then use LINQ to XML to parse the XML to a bound listbox itemsource.

I am thinking I need to use a variation of the below for each class, but would like some help.

```
HtmlNodeCollection cols = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//td[@class='flight']");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `InnerText` which strips out the HTML.

Use `InnerHtml`:

```
string rate = rateNode.InnerHtml;
```

You can create an XML document from this string (assuming it is valid XML).

You can also query the `rateNode` in the same way you retrieved it - selecting its child nodes:

```
var firstRow = rateNode.SelectSingleNode("./table/tbody/tr[0]");
string origin = firstRow.SelectSingleNode("./td[@class = 'origin']");
```

Comment: Any chance of example code? Im having trouble getting my head around parsing multiple classes in that div and then to xml

Comment: thanks for that, I seem to have it working although it only returns the first results and there are hundreds that it needs to return

Comment: @Rhys - You probably need a node set, not a single node. Something like: `var rows = rateNode.SelectNodes("./table/tbody/tr");` and iterate over the result.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just realised I was on VS 2010 not VS 2010 for windows phone. I have to start from scratch :(

Comment: My other question is [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267961/html-agilty-for-wp7-silverlight-c] if you feel like helping me out some more.

Comment: Sorry if this is a basic question, but what do you mean by iterate over the results?

Comment: @Rhys - loop over. Go through the items in the list one at a time. Search for the iterator pattern.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to work with linq to xml, you can transform the HtmlDocument to a xml string:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.SourceURL");  
doc.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Xml.XmlTextWriter xw = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(sw);
doc.Save(xw);
string result = sw.ToString();
```

Then you only need create an XDocument objet and load with the xml string:

```
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xDoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(result);
```

And now you have a XDocument to play with Linq.

Comment: But this will only work if the html is valid xml. The HtmlAgilityPack also works with plain html.

Comment: It can output valid XML. I just missed to add the doc.OptionOutputAsXml = true; sentence

Comment: @alejandro thanks for that. But, the HTML is not XML and very messy, so the HTML agility pack is probably my best option. I gave you an up for the suggestion though.