# HTML Agilty for WP7 - Silverlight c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, windows-phone-7, html-agility-pack

I am currently trying to parse specfic Tables from a DIV in an HTML doc.

I had this working windows Silverlight, but WP7 HTML agility pack seems to be a different thing altogether.

HTML Looks like this

```
<div id="FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel">

   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody>
     <tr class="">
     <td class="airline"><img src="/images/airline logos/NZ.gif" title="AIR NEW ZEALAND LIMITED. " alt="AIR NEW ZEALAND LIMITED. " /></td>
     <td class="flight">NZ8</td>
     <td class="codeshare">&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="origin">San Francisco</td>
     <td class="date">01 Sep</td>
     <td class="time">17:15</td>
     <td class="est">18:00</td>
     <td class="status">DEPARTED</td>
     </tr>
```

I am currently using this code to parse the tables inside the "FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel" DIV Box

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace Auckland_Airport
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml("http://www.SourceURL");

            var flightTableCell = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                 .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID = "FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel")
                 .Element("table")
                 .Element("tbody")
                 .Elements("td")
                 .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attributes.Contains("flight"));

            var value = flightTableCell.InnerText;
```

This is producing an unhandled exception error:

```
MainPage.PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

Comment: What's your actual question? How to bind a IEnumerable to a ListBox ?

Comment: TextBox or ListBox? Can you decide? And what's not working with your current code, where you're fetching content?

Comment: @claus Jorgensen Either OR, I just need to know how to parse from the HTML and output. I need to know how to convert id to string. Sorry the code above could be completely wrong, HTML Agilty pack for wp7 is very different than the standard pack.

Comment: So you haven't even TRIED your own code?

Comment: @claus jorgensen I have been unable to find an examples of how to use this agility pack. Thats why I am asking for help. I have spend hours trying variations of the above, but am unable to work it out. If you have any suggestions then please offer them. If not please dont comment.

Comment: It's necessary to figure out what your actual problem is in the first place, before answers can be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this then:

```
var flightTableCell =
    doc.DocumentNode
        .Descendants("div")
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel")
        .Element("table")
        .Element("tbody")
        .Elements("td")
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attributes.Contains("flight"));

var value = flightTableCell.InnerText;  
this.textBlock1.Text = value;
```

Since you can't use xpath, you're forced to manually traverse the DOM.

Comment: Jorgensen Thanks for the suggestions, I will give this a try later tonight.

Comment: Jorgensen HTML agility pack doens't have a defination for ID, can you explain how that would work?

Comment: @Rhys It does on my screen, so you're clearly using a bad version of the HtmlAgilityPack. See my mirror:   http://github.com/Windcape/HtmlAgilityPackWP/blob/master/HAPPhone/HtmlNode.cs#L296

Comment: I have added your version of HAPPhone and still get the same issue. I have updated my code maybe you could take a look . Thanks

Comment: Two errors. It's **Id** , and you need to use **==** , yet another reason not to copy&paste without thinking :P

Comment: Thanks, but now I get an unhandled exception. Probably due to the html being full of multiple other divs and JS

Comment: Perhaps you should consider learning the basics of C# before you continue with this then?

Comment: Being able to understand compilation errors, or read exception messages, have a lot to do with basic C#. And since you can't do either, a beginners guide would be a good place to start.

Comment: thanks for you help anyway. You probably right. I do need to study up the basics.